# How to show date in format('M j, Y') in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have some dates in my database and would like to display it in `format('M j, Y')`

Tried `$course->date->format('M j, Y')`  But getting an error `Call to a member function format() on a non-object`

What is the best way to solve it?

Comment: what is `$course->date`?

Comment: I'm getting a date from database.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$course->created_at` ?

Comment: I have another field expect created_at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell Eloquent which columns are dates beyond the standard `updated_at` and `created_at` in order for it to parse them into Carbon objects for you.

It's as simple as adding `protected $dates = [...];` to your `Course` model.

```
class Course extends Eloquent
{
    ...

    protected $dates = ['startdate', 'enddate']; // <- columns to parse as Carbon objects

    ...
}
```

And now you can access each via `$course->startdate` and `$course->enddate`. So `$course->startdate->format('M j, Y')` will return a formatted `startdate`.

Comment: Is this gonna work then? 
`$course->date->format('M j, Y')`

I have two dates fields. startdate and enddate.

I didnt exaclt understand how this works

Comment: Then change `date` to `startdate` etc

Answer (score 2):

for php 5.4 +

```
{{(new DateTime($course->date))->format('M j, Y')}}
```

for php 5.3

```
$date = new DateTime($course->date);
echo $date->format('M j, Y');
```